# R: Adding names as indexes, instead of numbers

Tags: r, machine-learning

I've got a vector with some values, and I want to replace the vector indexing by names. So, I want to replace `[1,] [2,] [3,]` by some names like this:

Here are the beta values without names:

```
 [1,]  9.335256626
 [2,]  0.031369303
 [3,] -0.050801928
 [4,] -0.513624383
 [5,] -3.714115555
 [6,]  0.022378632
 [7,]  .          
 [8,] -0.599622031
 [9,]  0.494720259
[10,]  .          
[11,] -0.106661630
[12,] -0.007580542
[13,]  0.117596852
[14,] -0.125227171
```

And I am trying to add names like this:

```
(Intercept)  9.335256626
zn           0.031369303
indus       -0.050801928
chas        -0.513624383
nox         -3.714115555
rm           0.022378632
age          .          
dis         -0.599622031
rad          0.494720259
tax          .          
ptratio     -0.106661630
black       -0.007580542
lstat        0.117596852
medv        -0.125227171
```

This is what I did till now:

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)
Boston=na.omit(Boston)
x=model.matrix(crim~.,Boston)[,-1]
y=as.matrix(Boston$crim)
lasso.mod =glmnet(x,y, alpha =1, lambda = 0.1)
beta=coef(lasso.mod)
rownames(beta)=c() #Here I removed the names just to try to add them
```

I tried this `rownames(beta[,-1])=colnames(x)` but I get an error: **Error in dimnamesGets(x, value) : 
  invalid dimnames given for “dgCMatrix” object**

Comment: the syntax is `row.names()` so, try `row.names(beta)<-c("(Intercept)","zn","indus","chas","nox","rm","age","dis","rad","tax","ptratio","black","lstat","medv")`

Comment: @MichaelVine thank you this worked

Answer (score 0):

Just use `as.data.frame.matrix` to turn `beta` into a `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(beta)
#                      s0
#(Intercept)  9.335256626
#zn           0.031369303
#indus       -0.050801928
#chas        -0.513624383
#nox         -3.714115555
#rm           0.022378632
#age          0.000000000
#dis         -0.599622031
#rad          0.494720259
#tax          0.000000000
#ptratio     -0.106661630
#black       -0.007580542
#lstat        0.117596852
#medv        -0.125227171
```

To turn rownames into a column you can use `tibble::rownames_to_column`:

```
tibble::rownames_to_column(as.data.frame.matrix(beta))
```